# How can I setup a consistent python/django/virtualenv environment on my localhost, using my production settings?

Tags: python, django

On my production server I have python 2.5.2 and django 1.1 installed in a virtualenv directory. I use pip as well. My production server runs on Debian.

On my local pc I run ubuntu and I'd like to have consistent packaging. I have wanted to play with fabric so I now want to setup the same exact environment locally.

I don't have django installed locally, and I have a system wide Python 2.6.5. Can anyone offer advice as to what I need to do in order to reproduce the environment locally? I have generated a requirements.txt file on the production server, which now consists of:

```
  1 Django==1.2.1
  2 distribute==0.6.10
  3 wsgiref==0.1.2
  4 yolk==0.4.1
```

How can I use this locally? And how can I setup the same python version in a virtualenv locally?

Answer (score 2):

Create a virtual instance mimicing your production environment. This will enable you to have a sandbox setup exactly like your production environment. Try [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) :-)

Comment: I actually do have VirtualBox. Do you think it'd be worth it to just use the same Debian version locally instead of setting up a Virtualbox? Or are there other reasons you can think of for having a vbox setup?

Comment: The advantage of having a Virtual machine setup is that you can try things out before deployment to test without messing up your local machine and stopping the dev or killing production. All you need is to setup the vm, keep a good working copy of it and then test away on a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 1):

zc.buildout is a good tool for this, but it's not useful "after the fact". But for future projects you might want to consider using it. You then make a configuration file that builds the environment. You can then replicate it by just checking out the configuration file and running a couple of scripts.

I wouldn't be caught without it.

But, it won't exactly help you now. I hope the answer still might be helpful in the future though.